# YUI set cookies expire time

Tags: javascript, yui

I am working on in YUI framework with my client. I have a difficult to set a cookies expire by following YUI syntax.

According to the example, in here: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/cookie/#creatingcookies

I can create a cookies by setting up expire date. However, I tried to set the cookies will expire in 4 hours. It doesnot create a cookies at all.

```
var output = Y.DataType.Date.format(new Date(), {format:"%H"}); //Show the current hours
var expireTime= output+4; // 4 hours later, the cookies will expire

YAHOO.util.Cookie.set("name", "value", {
    expires: new Date(expireTime)
});
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong in here?

Cheers,
Qing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a Date instance 4 hours in the future:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 4);
```

You can then use "d" as the "expires" value.

Your code asks for a *formatted* Date, which means you're asking for a string. Thus the resulting value of your "expireTime" variable will be a string consisting of the hours digits from the time, with a "4" character appended. So if it were 10 o'clock, you'd get "104" for "expireTime".